# ios not invoking a return when using ngx-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: ios, ionic4, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using ngx-google-places-autocomplete to retrieve cities in an ionic 4 app.

```js
  // Add desired cities to intPlaces array
  handleDesiredCityChange(cities: any): void {
    console.log('cities', cities.formatted_address);
    this.intDestination.push(cities.formatted_address);
    console.log('this.intDestination new', this.intDestination);
    this.futureDest.nativeElement.value = null;
  }
```

```html
  <ion-card>
    <ion-label><strong>Future Destinations</strong></ion-label>
    <ion-card>
        <div>
          <input expand="block" #futureDest ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='options'
            #placesRef="ngx-places" (onAddressChange)="handleDesiredCityChange($event)" />
        </div>
      <div class="chipTest" *ngFor="let intPlace of intDestination">
        {{ intPlace }}
        <span class="closebtn" (click)="deletePlace(intPlace)">&times;</span>
      </div>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-card>
```

On an android device if you type in a city name and click it it's addded to the chips like the following:

[image]

In iOS if you click the city name it doesn't add it to the chip array...the name just remains in the input and it's never added to this.intDestination.push(cities.formatted_address);

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

after further investigation it's not specific to ios.  It happens in Android also

Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.  It doesn't recognize .push on the array prototype

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I I'm pulling information from the database and if that field was initially null it would cause that issue.  So I used the following:

```
    this.intDestination = data.data().intDestination ? data.data().intDestination : [],
```